# What is the use case for gs?

Tags: normal-mode

According to the documentation for `gs`:

> go to sleep for N seconds (default 1)

Thus you can put Vim to sleep for 10 seconds using `10gs`. What is a good use case for this command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: None. That is, I believe it is a waste to map the easily accessible keys `gs` to `sleep`.

---

With that said, I often use the the `:sleep` command when I do testing and debugging of vimscript files. So the command itself is not useless. But when I do use it, I use it as part of a vimscript. After ~15 years of using Vim, I have never used `gs` to make Vim sleep.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, when can `:sleep` be useful for testing or debugging of vimscript files. Maybe just one example.

Comment: Two examples: [Example 1](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/122db6a2d9706788510dd0d0ce0b48c51768afa6/autoload/vimtex/view/common.vim#L119) and [example 2](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/ad9c09b540607e054c1ba028df34cd8b67b08a56/test/issues/891/minivimrc#L26). Both examples use `sleep` to ensure that some backgrounded processes finish properly before continuing execution. In the last example, I have automated a test of some vimtex commands, and `sleep` is handy here also to give some time to inspect output before continuing execution.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve used it in macros. For instance, if there’s an asynchronous task (like format on save) that needs to complete before the rest of your macro continues, you can throw a `1gs` in there, it’ll get saved to your macro, and it will pause there for 1 second before it continues